# Excel copy and paste to lastrow some columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy all rows and some columns from sheet (one) to sheet (two). My code only copies the first 64 records.  I have tried it different ways wirh vba.  I have two command buttons each try it a different way.  Both only give me the first 64 rows.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
Dim I As Integer
I = 2

    Worksheets("two").Activate
   
    Range("A1:F1").Font.Bold = True
    Range("A1:F1").Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    Range("A1:F1").Font.Size = 14
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Last"
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "First"
    Columns("A:f").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Wife"
    ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Phone"
    ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value = "B Day"
    Worksheets("Two").Range("A1:F1").Font.Bold = True
    Worksheets("Two").Range("A1:F1").Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    Worksheets("Two").Range("A1:F1").Font.Size = 14
    Worksheets("Two").Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Worksheets("One").Activate

    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 2 To lastrow
        Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 1).Copy
        erow = Worksheets("Two").Cells(Rows.Count + 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow + 1, 1)
        Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 2).Copy
        Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow + 1, 2)
        Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 3).Copy
        Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow + 1, 3)
        Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 4).Copy
        Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow + 1, 4)
        Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 10).Copy
        Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow + 1, 5)
        Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 18).Copy
        Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow + 1, 6)

    Next I

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   
    Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit
    
    Worksheets("two").Activate
    Worksheets("Two").Range("A2").Activate
 
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim a As String
Dim b As String

a = Worksheets("one").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 2 To a
        If Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 20).Value = 1 Then
        Worksheets("One").Rows(I).Copy
        Worksheets("One").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Two").Cells(Rows, Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Two").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("One").Activate
    End If
    
    Next I
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("one").Cells(1, 1).Select
    Worksheets("two").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: You have multiple uses of finding the last row.  You cannot add 1 to `Rows.Count` since that would be more than the number of rows on a sheet.  Your first instance defining `LastRow` is correct.  `Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Also, on the second sub you declare `a` and `b` as strings.  They should be `Long`

Answer (score 0):

Begin by replacing:

```
erow = Worksheets("Two").Cells(Rows.Count + 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

with:

```
erow = Worksheets("Two").Cells(Rows.Count ,1).End(xlUp).Row+1
```

*There my be other errors*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `Copy/Paste` and avoiding `Activate` and `Select`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim erow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    I = 2
   
    With Worksheets("Two")
            .Range("A1").Value = "Last"
            .Range("B1").Value = "First"
            .Columns("A:f").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Range("C1").Value = "Wife"
            .Range("D1").Value = "Phone"
            .Range("E1").Value = "B Day"
            .Range("A1:F1").Font.Bold = True
            .Range("A1:F1").Font.Name = "Tahoma"
            .Range("A1:F1").Font.Size = 14
            .Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 2 To lastrow
        erow = Worksheets("Two").Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow, 1) = Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 1)
        Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow, 2) = Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 2)
        Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow, 3) = Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 3)
        Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow, 4) = Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 4)
        Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow, 5) = Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 10)
        Worksheets("Two").Cells(erow, 6) = Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 18)
    Next I

    Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    
    a = Worksheets("One").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 2 To a
        If Worksheets("One").Cells(I, 20).Value = 1 Then
            b = Worksheets("Two").Cells(Rows, Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Worksheets("Two").Rows(b) = Worksheets("One").Rows(I)
     End If
    
    Next I
  
End Sub
```